# Non-Linear Crystals (BBO) splitting photons

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement, non-linear-optics, photonics

So from what I've studied till now about Photon Entanglement is that when we input a photon of a particular wavelength ($\lambda$) into a BBO crystal (a non linear $\chi^2$ crystal), it has a **probability** of the photon to split into two photons with wavelength $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that energy is conserved $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$$

My question: What is the reason (based on a material related explanation, that is why non-linear crystals specifically) for the photon to split. What is the reason behind there being a probability for this phenomenon

Comment: Calling a crystal non-linear means that the material allows for mixing between different wavelengths. This applies to frequency doubling (two photons go in, one comes out) or the various options for BBO. What do you mean by a 'material related explanation' - what kind of an answer would be good?

Comment: @JonCuster what interaction is exactly happening with the crystal lattice such that such a phenomenon is happening. All the answers till now are like the light goes into a machine and two photons come out. What is happening inside the machine?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics may have more info. But, basically, the electric field of the light disturbs the atomic positions. In a non-centro-symmetric crystal that means the crystal field is shifted. This anharmonicity leads to sum/difference frequency mixing.

Comment: @JonCuster i did go through that reasoning in the wiki page. But I wanted a more elaborate answer on bow anharmonicity leads to different frequencies.

Comment: The page also mentions that the crystal induces harmonics in light. Which I did not get. Apart from that there is a consideration of some virtual states, which is also not well put

Comment: It's explained under "Nonlinearities as a wave-mixing process". The induced electric dipole moment oscillates at harmonics of the driving field, and this dipole moment in turn generates propagating waves at these harmonics. This corresponds to for example two photons combining into one. In QM the reverse process, down-conversion, has to be possible in order to preserve unitarity.